# When to convert Dates from Gregorian To Persian inside rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails application prompts users to enter some preferred dates in a html form. For this purpose I use a Persian date picker without any problems. Next these dates are passed alongside some other parameters to the controller and finally a new instance of my model should be created.

In addition I have the means to convert these dates from Persian calendar to Gregorian calendar. The problem is that I am not sure when to make the conversion.

Should it be inside the controller when receiving the parameters or Model?

In case of controller, do I have to do the conversion one by one for each date I get inside parameters hash or is there anyway to streamline the process?

In case of model, using callbacks seems to be a good idea but which ones? Are before_create and before_save sufficient?

Comment: Perform the conversion wherever you perform other sanitising of data - even if they were Gregorian dates, you would want to validate them and convert them to abstract data types as soon as possible.

Comment: @IMSopa I believe the convention in rails is to take care of validation in model and there are a wide range of Validation Helpers available to us. I want to do the conversion before saving the item to database and again after loading it from database in order to present to user in view. I am new to rails and want to make sure if I am sticking to the convention.

Comment: Yes, before_save would be the callback to use. For picking from DB, you could create a method in your model, say "def persian_date(date)" in which you will define the conversion, and then in show view, summon "Model.persian_date(@mode.date1)", "Model.persian_date(@mode.date2)" etc.. This is one of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In a future version of Rails https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32190 will help with some of this.